# Setup google Admob in Game SDL Android

Tags: admob, sdl

I have a problem for seting google admob into my project.
My project is a android game project, I use SDL on Android Studio.
For now, I cannot show google admob in my game.
I have found a lot of the way on google, stackoverfollows, liscourse.libsdl.org. But all are not successfull.
This my code of SDLActivity.java, function OnCreate.
The Ads it not showing.
Can Anyone can support me this one ?. Thank so much.

```
AdView adView;
AdRequest request;
// Setup
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Device: " + Build.DEVICE);
    Log.v(TAG, "Model: " + Build.MODEL);
    Log.v(TAG, "onCreate()");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

        }
    });

    adView = new AdView( this );
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

    request = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

    try {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("SDLActivity");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "modify thread properties failed " + e.toString());
    }

    // Load shared libraries
    String errorMsgBrokenLib = "";
    try {
        loadLibraries();
        mBrokenLibraries = false; /* success */
    } catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        mBrokenLibraries = true;
        errorMsgBrokenLib = e.getMessage();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        mBrokenLibraries = true;
        errorMsgBrokenLib = e.getMessage();
    }

    if (mBrokenLibraries)
    {
        mSingleton = this;
        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dlgAlert.setMessage("An error occurred while trying to start the application. Please try again and/or reinstall."
              + System.getProperty("line.separator")
              + System.getProperty("line.separator")
              + "Error: " + errorMsgBrokenLib);
        dlgAlert.setTitle("SDL Error");
        dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Exit",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close current activity
                    SDLActivity.mSingleton.finish();
                }
            });
       dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
       dlgAlert.create().show();

       return;
    }

    // Set up JNI
    SDL.setupJNI();

    // Initialize state
    SDL.initialize();

    // So we can call stuff from static callbacks
    mSingleton = this;
    SDL.setContext(this);

    mClipboardHandler = new SDLClipboardHandler();

    mHIDDeviceManager = HIDDeviceManager.acquire(this);

    // Set up the surface
    mSurface = new SDLSurface(getApplication());


    mLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

    adView.loadAd(request);
    adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mLayout.addView(mSurface);
    mLayout.addView(adView, params);

    // Get our current screen orientation and pass it down.
    mCurrentOrientation = SDLActivity.getCurrentOrientation();
    // Only record current orientation
    SDLActivity.onNativeOrientationChanged(mCurrentOrientation);

    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24) {
            mCurrentLocale = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
        } else {
            mCurrentLocale = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
        }
    } catch(Exception ignored) {
    }

    setContentView(mLayout);

    setWindowStyle(false);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(this);

    // Get filename from "Open with" of another application
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null && intent.getData() != null) {
        String filename = intent.getData().getPath();
        if (filename != null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Got filename: " + filename);
            SDLActivity.onNativeDropFile(filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?